# Condition for a Birth-Death chain to be transient

Tags: probability

We consider a Markov chain on $\{0,1,..\}$ such that the only non zero transitions from state $i$ are $i-1$ and $i+1$ with probabilities respectively $p_i$ and $q_i$.

So we define $\displaystyle \alpha_k=\frac{q_1}{p_1}\frac{q_2}{p_2}...\frac{q_{k-1}}{p_{k-1}}$

I am asked to prove that  the chain is transient if and only if

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k < \infty$

**EDIT**: Maybe I found a better way:

As it is a sum of positive terms it can either converge or go to infinity, it can't oscillate.
Assume the sum diverges 
Then we have that, if $h_i$ is the probability of reaching $0$ from $i$,
$h_i=1-(1-h_1)\sum_{k=1}^{i}\alpha_k$

But then as all the $h_i\in [0,1]$ we must have $h_1=1$ as otherwise the $h_i$ would be eventually outside the right range.
But then $h_i=1 \forall i$ which means that $0$ is recurrent.
So the chain is recurrent and we proved one direction by contrapositive.

For the converse I did the following:
if the chain is transient then $0$ is transient and then $\forall i$ $(1-h_1)\sum_{k=1}^{i} \alpha_k$ is in $(0,1]$ so it is an increasing bounded sequence and so it converges.

I am not entirely sure that this makes sense though, I think I am missing something...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For the MC to be transient it is enough for $q_i >\frac{1}{2} \ \forall i$

Comment: @Alex But so that series would not converge...I'm not following you here!

Comment: In the last edit you removed the definition of your $h_i$.

Comment: @joriki thanks !!

Comment: @Moritzplatz Could you explain why $h_i$ has that explicit form $1-(1-h_1)\sum_{k=1}^i\alpha_k?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think there is a mistake in your statement: $P(i,i-1)=p_i,\ P(i,i+1)=q_i$ If you $p_i=1,\ q_i=0$, then $0$ must be recurrent, but $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_k=0<\infty$. Hence, $P(i,i+1)=p_i,\ P(i,i-1)=q_i$.

Proof:

Define $\varphi(n):=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\alpha_m=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\frac{q_j}{p_j}$, then  $\varphi(X_n)$ is a martingale, and you can check this by definition. If $a<x<b,\ (a,b,x\mbox{ are integers}),\ T=T_a\wedge T_b$, then $\varphi(X_{n\wedge T})$ is a bounded martingale.

We can compute $P_x(T_a>T_b)=\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(a)}{\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)}$, let $a=0,b=M$, we obtain $P_x(T_0>T_m)=\frac{\varphi(x)}{\varphi(M)}$ .Then

$$ 0 \mbox{ is recurrent if and only if } \varphi(M)\to \infty \ as\  M\to \infty  
$$

Note that $\varphi(\infty)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k$